# Can't generate the correct class

Tags: c#, json

I'm in trouble with this json:

```
{
"tester": [
    {
      "type": {
        "ID": "R89d",
        "Description": "Test",
        "lastUpdated": "2016-03-20 20:45:09",
      },
      "specification": {}
    },
    {
      "type": {
        "ID": "RB01",
        "Description": "Another test",
        "lastUpdated": null
      },
      "specification": {
        "0": {
          "ID": "RB01",
          "number": 1,
          "Type": "RB"
        },
        "1": {
          "ID": "RB01",
          "number": 3,
          "Type": "RB"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "type": {
        "ID": "RT40",
        "Description": "Test 2",
        "lastUpdated": null,
      },
      "specification": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

in particular when I put it into [json2c#](http://json2csharp.com/) site I got this class:

```
public class Type
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__0
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class __invalid_type__1
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Specification
{
    public __invalid_type__0 __invalid_name__0 { get; set; }
    public __invalid_type__1 __invalid_name__1 { get; set; }
}

public class Tester
{
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public Specification specification { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Tester> tester { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know why the site return me `invalid type` 'cause the json syntax is correct. My goal is create a class that allow me to read all properties of `specification`, how you can see in the json there is an array of object. What I need to do is create something that allow me to access to all `specification` object value as `ID - Number - Type`. Actually I managed it only with Type with something like this:

```
string responseText = "json above";
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);

foreach(var item in obj.Tester){ //loop through Tester item
    //what I need: 

    foreach(var spec in item.specification){ //not possible 
        spec.Description; ...
    } 
}
```

Comment: While the JSON syntax is correct, that doesn't mean it can make a valid C# type for it.  The JSON you've posted would result in property names of `0` and `1`, which aren't valid.  Is there a chance you can recraft your JSON output to something that's an _actual_ array, rather than being an object with array-like properties?  Whilst you'll be able to spend time deserialising this in some fashion, a quicker/cleaner approach may well be to fix the source.

Comment: Also `type` seems problematic given the current `Type` class generated.

Comment: @JamesThorpe well I can only remove the `"0"` and `"1"` I don't know if this edit could help. This: http://pastebin.com/LXPzrmjJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
"specification": {
        "0": {
          "ID": "RB01",
          "number": 1,
          "Type": "RB"
        },
        "1": {
          "ID": "RB01",
          "number": 3,
          "Type": "RB"
        }
```

In c# names cannot start with digit. Generator cannot name type "0" and "1"

**EDIT**

If you can change json then modify it in this way:

```
"specification": [
        {
          "ID": "RB01",
          "number": 1,
          "Type": "RB"
        },
        {
          "ID": "RB01",
          "number": 3,
          "Type": "RB"
        }
      ]
```

So change to array give this structure:

```
public class Type
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class Specification
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Tester
{
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public List<Specification> specification { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Tester> tester { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: so I should change the json structure? what do you propose? If I remove the digit: http://pastebin.com/LXPzrmjJ

Comment: You need to fix how your output JSON object is crafted.  @BWA is correct.

Comment: @Kixoka See my pastebin, I change my json structure removing the digit, maybe can help to solve the problem

Comment: @BWA I saw you edit, but a question: how can I access to each property of `specification` object as `Type`? should I define a new class?

Comment: @Dillinger sorry my bad, i'm baddy generate classes

Comment: No problems, I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Type
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string lastUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class Specification
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Tester
{
    public Type[] types { get; set; }
    public Specification[] specifications { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Tester> tester { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`specification` should be an array:

```
"specification": [
    {
        "ID": "RB01",
        "number": 1,
        "Type": "RB"
    },
    ....
]
```

and `c#` implementation too:

```
public class Tester
{
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public Specification[] specification { get; set; }
}
```

or `List<Specification>`:

```
public class Tester
{
    public Type type { get; set; }
    public List<Specification> specification { get; set; }
}
```

and `Specification` itself:

```
public class Specification
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int number { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Infact I changed my json like this: http://pastebin.com/LXPzrmjJ I'll try your solution